# В этой должности или на этой должности

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно:Вот уже 20 лет она работает в этой должности или на этой должности?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Нацкорпусе  встречаются оба варианта:

На этой должности он проработал до ухода на пенсию.  На этой должности судья не может работать более двух сроков подряд. У нас раньше работала девочка на этой должности,

В этой должности она работала до избрания в 1992 г. генеральным директором. В этой должности он проработает ровно 30 лет.

Answer (score 2):

Работают в должности, принимают на должность. [Как правильно: работать в должности или на должности](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Bsearch%2F%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=846.CQMiMrUrUV-FMrncnbzs4BtVRey2uXj718LBf2flhOnqI1JCXXfTENpzx8XCQc9GfYLCZr0oYuTh-rI9Cdviphx-9Pvv54iis1ywcWdckQo.f1805acffdaede9ca3034c8c8590a55fd269db5f&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.TextoLogia.ru%2Ffaq%2Fall-questions%2Fkak-pravilno-napisat-katya-rabotaet-v-dolzhnosti%2F962%2F%3Fq%3D492%26n%3D962&uuid=&state=PEtFfuTeVD5kpHnK9lio9bb4iM1VPfe4W5x0C0%2BqwflIRTTifi6VAA%3D%3D&data=&b64e=3&sign=7283449deee1e058d7a70949d95bf345&keyno=0&cst=AiuY0DBWFJ5fN_r-AEszkwH9g9wSLyOEhVVV6smiHWFqLEXowJBxUnt1h9VlUCK6lpGM8EEVWOyFVriTimSIj4XMZUZxq5s2GJyIoBVYggYi8UVdIjK44XM_cIhVS_onui9uRCw6awL8PMYtJYx2WsebEBtAk_N0Qs5-CM8YTgVYwbA-Ufr1G5Jha7phzov6&ref=cM777e4sMOAycdZhdUbYHpMQ80108_UCCIlkcOrsGUOP7ebdLg6P9gRCv28vQJWdtym2bEQp-WU5OYBGRIPVKQkVFcR-cYESZ1qLr1Z1yuKFqZ1y-1u-24HMu6ebNCDl-Pa96A-iLNk0cM0tfqxULn0ceOCS-sXSGKifmy2Mgsdhxz94WZeCyA6UwxeBZAVHShFHv75yMNtbDuynQFC-_WTRBmNft_85bY-OoHHJzQLBqLsO_R5nnQBBiaHzWSnDcMN78tYiZLs&l10n=ru&cts=1445272966962&mc=4.3894608760283615)

Comment: Спасибо Вам за быстрый ответ